# Sum in a column until it meets another category

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a google sheet to keep track of my money.
I'm pretty new to all this and I'm learning how to do a few things.

I'd like to build a table where I can have categories *(in green)* and their subcategories. So I'd like to be able to have the sum of the sub categories in front of their parent category.

**Also**, this is a template that is probably going to change over time, so I'd like it to be modular (it would be simple otherwise) if I add a new subcategory or even a new category.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Here is what I have managed to find and edit, maybe it's a great path... `=IF($A3="✹";SUM(E3:INDEX(E3:E;MATCH(TRUE;(A3:A="✫");3)));"")`
But actually it sums every row that has a *star* in the "A" column. It doesn't stop until it meet a *sun*

[here is the link to access the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HIkwgnoiOP9_9EIQy6IXXglmmdVOupMvUi7YqwrLyMM/edit?usp=sharing)

Also, I know that [Aspire Budget](https://aspirebudget.com/) works that way, but it's a bit too complicated and I need help to understand it...

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 added a link

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a "solve my homework" type question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1, 1))="✫", ROW()+1, "×"), 5)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MATCH("✹", INDIRECT("A"&ROW()+1&":A"), 0)+ROW()-1, 5))))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working just fine,
I'll have to look it up in order to understand it properly and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that works:

```
=
if(
  indirect("A"&(row()+1))="✫",
  sum(
    indirect(
      "E"&(row()+1)&":E"&vlookup(
        "✹",
        {
          indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A"),
          arrayformula(row(indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A")))
        },
        2,
        FALSE
      )-1
    )
  ),
  0
)
```

The basic idea is to search for the next `✹`. Then get the range between the two rows ad add them.

### Formula rundown

#### Step 1: Get the values starting after this row

This can be done using `indirect`. Basically it's `A<next row>:A`.

The number of row it's simply `row()`; and the next one `row()+1`.

So using indirect we get:

```
=
indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A")
```

#### Step 2: Find the next category

We want to have the number of the next category. This can be achieved using vlookup.

What we do is make an array with the value on the first column and the number of column on the second one. To get the number of row of a value `row` can be used. So it would like:

```
{
  <range>,
  arrayformula(row(<range>))
}
```

We need arrayformula to make sure it's used as a formula.

`<range>` would be the value on the last step so together it looks like:

```
=
{
  indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A"),
  arrayformula(row(indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A")))
}
```

Now we need to add the vlookup:

```
=
vlookup(
  "✹",
  {
    indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A"),
    arrayformula(row(indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A")))
  },
  2,
  FALSE
)
```

Which is basically getting the value of the first case of `✹`. So now we have the number of the next row of the category.

#### Step 3: Get the range in the middle

Now that we have the value we can get the range of the values to sum. This would be `E<next row>:E<row before next category>` or with a function:

```
indirect(
  "E"&<next row>&":E"&<next category row>-1
)
```

so next row is `row()+1` and the next category row is the result of the last step. Together:

```
=
indirect(
  "E"&(row()+1)&":E"&vlookup(
    "✹",
    {
      indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A"),
      arrayformula(row(indirect("A"&(row()+1)&":A")))
    },
    2,
    FALSE
  )-1
)
```

#### Step 4: sum

Now we can add sum to all of it. Nothing complicated here.

#### Step 5: Add conditional for empty categories

Some categories are empty so we need to check that the next row is an entry. This can be done with the simple if:

```
if(
  indirect("A"&(row()+1))="✫",
  <sum formula>,
  0
)
```

So if you put everything together you get the result.

### Final thoughts

Even though it seems massive the formula is not too complex. Try looking into it and let me know if there is something that's not clear enough.

### Refrences

- [VLOOKUP (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [SUM (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [ROW (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
- [INDIRECT (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
- [IF (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editor Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: Hi Martí,
Thanks a lot for all the references that will help me quite a lot.
I'll dive into it! :)

Comment: Note that player0's answer is probably simpler.